# Erlang: Job Scheduling Over a Dynamic Set of Nodes

Tags: erlang, scheduled-tasks

I need some advice writing a Job scheduler in Erlang which is able to distribute jobs ( external os processes) over a set of worker nodes. A job can last from a few milliseconds to a few hours. The "scheduler" should be a global registry where jobs come in, get sorted and then get assigned and executed on connected "worker nodes". Worker nodes should be able to register on the scheduler by telling how many jobs they are able to process in parallel (slots). Worker nodes should be able to join and leave at any time.

#### An Example:

- Scheduler has 10 jobs waiting
- Worker Node A connects and is able to process 3 jobs in parallel
- Worker Node B connects and is able to process 1 job in parallel
- Some time later, another worker node joins which is able to process 2 jobs in parallel

#### Questions:

I seriously spent some time thinking about the problem but I am still not sure which way to go. My current solution is to have a globally registered gen_server for the scheduler which holds the jobs in its state. Every worker node spawns N worker processes and registers them on the scheduler. The worker processes then pull a job from the scheduler (which is an infinite blocking call with {noreply, ...} if no jobs are currently availale).

Here are some questions:

- Is it a good idea to assign every new job to an existing worker, knowing that I will have to re-assign the job to another worker at the time new workers connect? (I think this is how the Erlang SMP scheduler does things, but reassigning jobs seems like a big headache to me)
- Should I start a process for every worker processing slot and where should this process live: on the scheduler node or on the worker node? Should the scheduler make rpc calls to the worker node or would it be better for the worker nodes to pull new jobs and then execute them on their own?
- And finally: Is this problem already solved and where to find the code for it? :-)
  I already tried RabbitMQ for job scheduling but custom job sorting and deployment adds a lot of complexity.

Any advice is highly welcome!

Comment: Have you already considered the `pool(3)` facility? They can be used to distribute load and add nodes dynamically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853750/erlang-starting-a-remote-node-programmatically/4854363#4854363 Or is it completely different to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, already considered it. But don't know how pool helps here. If I understand pool right, 100K incoming jobs coming in at the same time would spawn 100K processes across all registerd worker nodes. But this way I can not limit how many jobs are computed in parallel and adding additional nodes to handle the job load would not rebalance the jobs.

Comment: These "jobs" are they to be implemented in Erlang?

Comment: "job" in my case means an external os process which can last from a few milliseconds to a few hours.

Answer (score 4):

Having read your answer in the comments I'd still recommend to use `pool(3)`:

- Spawning 100k processes is not a big deal for Erlang because spawning a process is much cheaper than in other systems.
- One process per job is a very good pattern in Erlang, start a new process run the job in the process keeping all the state in the process and terminate the process after the job is done.
- Don't bother with worker processes that process a job and wait for a new one.  This is the way to go if you are using OS-processes or threads because spawning is expensive but in Erlang this only adds unnecessary complexity.

The `pool` facility is useful as a low level building block, the only thing it misses your your functionality is the ability to start additional nodes automatically.  What I would do is start with pool and a fixed set of nodes to get the basic functionality.

Then add some extra logic that watches the load on the nodes e.g. also like pool does it with `statistics(run_queue)`.  If you find that all nodes are over a certain load threshold just `slave:start/2,3` a new node on a extra machine and use `pool:attach/1`to add it to your pool.

This won't rebalance old running jobs but new jobs will automatically be moved to the newly started node since its still idle.

With this you can have a fast `pool` controlled distribution of incoming jobs and a slower totally separate way of adding and removing nodes.

If you got all this working and still find out -- after some real world benchmarking please -- you need rebalancing of jobs you can always build something into the jobs main loops, after a message `rebalance` it can respawn itself using the pool master passing its current state as a argument.

Most important just go ahead and build something simple and working and optimize it later.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem:

"distributor" - gen_server,
"worker" - gen_server.

"distributor" starts "workers" using slave:start_link, each "worker" is started with max_processes parameter,

```
"distributor" behavior:

handle_call(submit,...)
  * put job to the queue,
  * cast itself check_queue

handle_cast(check_queue,...)
  * gen_call all workers for load (current_processes / max_processes),
  * find the least busy,
  * if chosen worker load is < 1 gen_call(submit,...) worker 
      with next job if any, remove job from the queue,

"worker" behavior (trap_exit = true):

handle_call(report_load, ...)
  * return current_process / max_process,

handle_call(submit, ...)
  * spawn_link job,

handle_call({'EXIT', Pid, Reason}, ...)
  * gen_cast distributor with check_queue
```

In fact it is more complex than that as I need to track running jobs, kill them if I need to, but it is easy to implement in such architecture.

This is not a dynamic set of nodes though, but you can start new node from the distributor whenever you need.

P.S. Looks similar to pool, but in my case I am submitting port processes, so I need to limit them and have better control of what is going where.

Comment: What are you meaning with "submitting port processes"?

Comment: I mean "Ruby process" as a "job", even "Rails" to be more specific.

Comment: Did I miss something in the question?  I was reading that these jobs are Erlang only affairs. This would make a big difference for the solution to prefer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain what "job" means". Jobs are external os port processes lasting from a few milliseconds up to a few hours.